# Capturing mouse click count from the Background

Tags: bash, sh

How detect mouse click count on active screen.
I am trying xdotool click but is not working.i want mouse click count in current screen.

Comment: bash won't be able to detect GUI events like mouse clicks. If xdotool can't do, you'll need to find another tool that can.

Comment: What is the **active screen**? Do you mean that display device which the `DISPLAY` environment variable refers to?